# Returning to application after videoplayback

Tags: android, video, return, playback

I have an application that has a list of videos with a play button. When I click on video, a separate activity is called through intent. When the video is finished, it remains there and it doesn't go back to the original application unless I press back button. Is there any way in which the application returns back to the main activity after the video playback is finished? Here is the code for my video creation

```
public void onCreate(Bundle onSavedInsance) {
       super.onCreate(onSavedInsance);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        filename = extras.getString("videofilename");
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        mc = new MediaController(this);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
        mc.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(filename);
        //mVideoView.setVideoPath(video.getAbsolutePath());
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.start();

    }
```

Comment: Is the separate activity part of your application, or are you invoking the device's default handler for videos?

Comment: its a separate activity and is part of my application

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a VideoView, you can add a listener to determine when the video has finished playing:

```
mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: I am having one more problem. When the video is going on, I have to press back button twice to get to the mainApplication.. why this is so. It should go back on the first press. ?

Comment: Did the above code resolve the OP? You can trap the back button by overriding `onBackPressed()`.

Comment: the onBackPressed is working on the emulator when not on the device. Anyways sir, can you elaborate a bit more on onCompletion Listener. I am using MediaController. I have updated my question to put the Code as well so you can see how my video is shown.. Any suggestions sir to automatically finish the activity once the video is finished. ??

Comment: Simply copy/paste the code from my answer somewhere into your code after `findViewById()`.

Comment: I tried it Sir, it gave error and asked me to remove override notation. I did it but even then it doesn't finish the activity once the video is finished.. Any other suggestions??

Comment: The annotation error suggests you aren't using Java 1.6. The [functionality exists since API level 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29), so I would suggest debugging to figure out if it is being called at all.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1383/discussion-between-farhan-and-paul-lammertsma)

Comment: I tried the debugger and used Log.v to print a message; just to see if it is called or not.. but it is not called Sir!! I shall be greatly thankful to you if you help me here. I am using java 1.5

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you any further.

Comment: Thanks sir for your help... I hope someone else will be able to help me